# Turning tables in restaurants

Tags: translation, food

What are those turning tables called, that you often find in restaurants in China, that are used to hand around the dishes? We used them a lot when in China, but I can't seem to remember we ever talked about this specific piece of furniture. Can you just call it 转台 or 转桌 or something like that? I don't even know what to call them in another language, so it's pretty hard to find the right term.

Comment: 旋转餐桌, this is what I've heard most.

Comment: In English [Lazy Susan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_Susan).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some similar names.

餐桌旋转盘
[image]

旋转餐盘
[image]

转盘

[image]